# Extending Uniform Convergence of Polynomials From $\left[0,1\right]$ to $\mathbb{\overline{\mathbb{D}}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

This is a question that has been bothering me in my research to no end:

Let $\varphi$
  and the sequence $\left\{ \varphi_{n}\right\}$ 
  be complex-valued polynomial functions defined on the closed unit interval $\left[0,1\right]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$
  such that: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\underset{x\in\left[0,1\right]}{\sup}\left|\varphi\left(x\right)-\varphi_{n}\left(x\right)\right|=0$$
 i.e., the polynomials $\varphi_{n}$
  converge uniformly to a polynomial $\varphi$
  on $\left[0,1\right]$
 . Since polynomials always extend to entire functions, it seems almost obvious that the given convergence on $\left[0,1\right]$
  would imply uniform convergence on the closed unit disk $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$
 :$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\underset{\left|z\right|\leq1}{\sup}\left|\varphi\left(z\right)-\varphi_{n}\left(z\right)\right|=0$$
 However, I am not entirely sure if this is true, nor how to prove it.

I have showed, however—by assuming otherwise and exploiting Montel's Theorem using the assumption $\left|\varphi_{n}\left(z\right)-\varphi\left(z\right)\right|>\epsilon$
  for all $z$
  in an open set $U\subseteq\mathbb{D}\backslash\left[0,1\right]$—that: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\varphi\left(z\right)-\varphi_{n}\left(z\right)\right|=0$$
 pointwise for all $z\in\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Clarification on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: For $n=1,2,\dots$ we can choose a polynomial $p_n$ such that

$$|p_n(z) - \frac{e^{inz}}{n}| \le \frac{1}{n}\,\,\text {for } z\in \overline {\mathbb D}.$$

(For example, we could take $p_n$ to be a Taylor polynomial of $\dfrac{e^{inz}}{n}$ at $0$ of sufficiently high degree.)  It follows that $p_n\to 0$ uniformly on $[-1,1].$ However, if $z= x+iy$ with $y<0,$ then $|\dfrac{e^{inz}}{n}|= e^{n|y|}/n \to \infty.$ Thus for any $z\in \overline {\mathbb D}$ above the real axis, we will have $|p_n(z)|\to \infty.$

Comment: Interesting. What if we also made one or both of the following two changes to the hypotheses / conclusions: 

1) $\varphi\left(0\right)=\varphi_{n}\left(0\right)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$ and that $\varphi\left(z\right)$ was not identically $0$? Would a similar counterexample still exist?

2) Instead of uniform convergence on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$
 , suppose we only want uniform convergence on a compact subset $K$
  of $\mathbb{D}$ such that $\left[0,1\right]\subseteq K$
  and for which the interior of $K$ is non-empty.

Comment: 1) Consider $z(p_n(z)+1)$ where the $p_n$ are as described above. 2) If that interior contains points in the lower half plane, then the first counterexample applies. I'm thinking you can guess what to do if an interior point is in the upper half plane.

Answer (score 0):

There actually *is* a way to accomplish this extension: use the Poisson Kernel.

Instead of considering a sequence of polynomials $\varphi_{n}$
  in $x$
  on the unit interval, consider a sequence of polynomials $\varphi_{n}$
  in $e^{2\pi it}$
  for $t$
  in the unit interval (such that $\varphi_{n}\left(0\right)=\varphi_{n}\left(1\right)$
  for all $n$
 ). Then, by the Poisson integral formula, we can extend both the $\varphi_{n}$s and their limit, $\varphi$
 , to holomorphic functions $\psi_{n}$
  and $\psi$
 :$$\psi_{n}\left(z\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\varphi_{n}\left(t\right)\textrm{Re}\left(\frac{e^{2\pi it}+z}{e^{2\pi it}-z}\right)dt,\textrm{ }\forall\left|z\right|<1$$
 and:$$\psi\left(z\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\varphi\left(t\right)\textrm{Re}\left(\frac{e^{2\pi it}+z}{e^{2\pi it}-z}\right)dt,\textrm{ }\forall\left|z\right|<1$$
 Since the poisson kernel is bounded on all compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$
 , and since the $\varphi_{n}$s converge uniformly in $t$
 , $\psi_{n}$
  converges compactly to $\psi$ on the open unit disk.

Thus, the moral of the story is that you can extend the polynomials' limit to a holomorphic function by way of that function's values the unit circle.